# How can I reduce rspec test dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, models, shoulda

If 1 test fails, tons of others do.
How could I change this so that the other checks (the "it's") below only get done if should be_valid is true, i.e. how can I nest the following "it"'s.  I can create a different context for all the other ones and have be_valid on its own but how do I ensure that they are dependent (in a good way in this case! e.g. they won't run).

```
describe Gorilla do
  context "is valid" do
    subject { Factory.build(:gorilla) }
    it { should be_valid }
    it { should have_many :gorilla_memberships}
    it { should have_many(:gorilla_groups).through(:gorilla_memberships) }
    it { should have_many :gorilla_observations }
    it { should have_one(:avatar).through(:gorilla_observations) }
    it { should have_one(:noseprint).through(:gorilla_observations) }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit support for creating any sort of relationship between examples in rspec.

Comment: Thanks, how about either :before or nesting, could that help me?

Comment: You might be able to hack something together by nesting the dependent examples and including a before(:all) in the nested group that queries the metadata of its parent example group looking for a failure, and then pops all of its examples before any of them run. I'm not certain it would work, and I am skeptical of its value and quite certain it would gum up your specs, but to each his own :)

Comment: I hate gum and if it's not the right approach then I won't bother with the hack.  Thanks :)